# What is the difference between these three ways to initialise static variables?

Tags: c++, c++11

Those 2 syntaxes work. What is the difference between them?

```
class MyClass
{
  const static int myInt1_ {20};
  const static int myInt2_ = 20;
}
```

Also, why is it not possible to do `const static int myInt3_ (20)`?

Comment: The language designers decided they didn't want to allow `const static int myInt3_ (20);` in this context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const static int myInt1_ {20};
```

This is the newer uniform initialization syntax that was introduced in the C++11 revision. Prior to C++11 only

```
const static int myInt1_ = 20;
```

would be valid. Uniform initialization syntax was introduced to resolve some parsing ambiguities in more complex initialization constructs. In your case, with simple static class member initialization, both initialization syntaxes are valid and produce identical results.

Comment: Don't braces prevent narrowing conversions?

Answer (score 3):

The differences between brace and equals initialization for various classes can be involved, so I'm going to restrict to answering for integers. For integers there is basically one difference: narrowing conversions. This compiles:

```
const static int x = 3.0;
```

This does not.

```
const static int x{3.0};
```